# How to process SASS/LESS in GruntJS

Tags: sass, less, gruntjs, compass-sass

Is there a version of [grunt-processhtml](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-processhtml) for SASS/LESS ?
In my scss I need to set variable `$icon-font-path` (yes, bootstrap) to different values depending whether we are in dev mode or we are assembling production code.

The last thing I want to do is to move the variable declaration to a separate file (dev & prod version) and substitute them in my build process.

My Gruntfile: https://github.com/vucalur/django-wibses/blob/master/wibses/yo/Gruntfile.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there is a way, use `importPath` option of https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass, which would make files under the specified folder findable by Sass's @import directive.

```
compass: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      importPath: 'src/sass/icon-path-dev',
    }
  },
  prod: {
    options: {
      importPath: 'src/sass/icon-path-prod',
    }
  }
```

And icon-path-dev will have _filepathvar.scss which would have your variable as

```
$icon-font-path  : 'dev-font/path';
```

And icon-path-prod will have _filepathvar.scss which would have your variable as

```
$icon-font-path  : 'prod-font/path';
```

You can then use this under your main scss file like

`@import "filepathvar";`

Comment: I'm working on sth really custom (django + yeoman) and I might need SASS parsing in the future, that's why I didn't want to solve it with files substitution, but your solution is really elegant and allowed me to get rid of crazy hack in django urls. Great thanks!
I hope setup chores near completion and I won't need SASS parsing, but still I'm curious if that's possible directly...